# Data-labeling ChartJS, Removing Duplicates?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is there a good way to remove duplicate data labels in Chartjs? Or a good way to space labels out better above data points so they are not on top of each other?

```
Chart.plugins.register({
  afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart, easing) {
    // To only draw at the end of animation, check for easing === 1
    var ctx = chart.ctx;

    chart.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
      var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(i);
      if (!meta.hidden) {
        meta.data.forEach(function(element, index) {
          // Draw the text in black, with the specified font
          ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';

          var fontSize = 12;
          var fontStyle = 'normal';
          var fontFamily = 'Arial';
          ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(fontSize, fontStyle, fontFamily);

          // Just naively convert to string for now
          var dataString = dataset.data[index].toString();

          // Make sure alignment settings are correct
          ctx.textAlign = 'center';
          ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
          var bodySpacing = 3;
          var padding = 10;
          var position = element.tooltipPosition();
          ctx.fillText(dataString, position.x, position.y - (fontSize / 2) - padding);
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

[image]

To clarify, the data is my data. The code is taken from the chartjs sample data labeling page and basically pasted in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit this chart Style in chart.js library. It show list of all data on specific point. [Here is link](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/line-styles.html)

Comment: Ooo, that is nifty. Didn't see that. It looks like it works for tooltips, so I'm assuming I should just stick with the tooltips and not the plugin data labeling?